# Insert at a specific location in Ember.Array Object

Tags: ember.js

I know I can add a new element to `Ember.Array` object by using the following:

```
var ArrayObject.push({/*new element*/});
```

But I want to know if it is possible to put an element at a particular location easily like:

```
ArrayObject.insertAt(num, {/*new element*/}))
```

Note: I know the hard way by [slicing](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_slice) and [concatenating](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/merge-two-arrays/4774).

Comment: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.NativeArray.html#method_insertAt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer by @blessenm. It's in the `Ember.NativeArray` class where I can call the `insertAt()` method.